# ARRAYFORMULA() won't iterate over range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm trying to get all rows of data into a sheet where column headers match. Please have a look at [this sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VBSrUhVci79nZFKbmrBY2yGSUUWNdKJacYlwJXtuKaQ/edit?usp=sharing). I need to achieve this **dynamically** so I'm using `ARRAYFORMULA()`.

Source data

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |   H   |   I   |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | ID101 | ID999 | ID102 | ID103 | ID104 | ID105 | ID106 | ID107 | ID108 |
|  2 | 2     | 9     | 3     | 1     | 5     | 1     | 3     | 1     | 5     |
|  3 | 1     | 9     | 3     | 3     | 1     | 3     | 2     | 4     | 4     |
|  4 | 1     | 9     | 4     | 2     | 4     | 2     | 4     | 5     | 5     |
|  5 | 5     | 9     | 2     | 5     | 2     | 3     | 1     | 4     | 3     |
|  6 | 3     | 9     | 2     | 4     | 2     | 3     | 2     | 2     | 4     |
|  7 | 2     | 9     | 2     | 2     | 2     | 3     | 3     | 2     | 4     |
|  8 | 2     | 9     | 2     | 4     | 1     | 4     | 1     | 4     | 3     |
|  9 | 2     | 9     | 3     | 2     | 3     | 1     | 4     | 1     | 5     |
| 10 | 2     | 9     | 3     | 2     | 3     | 1     | 4     | 1     | 5     |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Formula input

```
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |   H   |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1 | ID101 | ID102 | ID103 | ID104 | ID105 | ID106 | ID107 | ID108 |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Expected result

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |   H   |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | ID101 | ID102 | ID103 | ID104 | ID105 | ID106 | ID107 | ID108 |
|  2 | 2     | 3     | 1     | 5     | 1     | 3     | 1     | 5     |
|  3 | 1     | 3     | 3     | 1     | 3     | 2     | 4     | 4     |
|  4 | 1     | 4     | 2     | 4     | 2     | 4     | 5     | 5     |
|  5 | 5     | 2     | 5     | 2     | 3     | 1     | 4     | 3     |
|  6 | 3     | 2     | 4     | 2     | 3     | 2     | 2     | 4     |
|  7 | 2     | 2     | 2     | 2     | 3     | 3     | 2     | 4     |
|  8 | 2     | 2     | 4     | 1     | 4     | 1     | 4     | 3     |
|  9 | 2     | 3     | 2     | 3     | 1     | 4     | 1     | 5     |
| 10 | 2     | 3     | 2     | 3     | 1     | 4     | 1     | 5     |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

---

Please consider the following formula in `Sheet1!A2`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:1),FILTER(Data!$A$2:$AAA,Data!$A1:1=G1),))`

The problem with this formula is `G1` in the second `FILTER()` parameter, which appears to be an absolute reference.

I've tried `G1:1` but that doesn't seem to trigger an iteration by `ARRAYFORMULA()`, which I find hard to understand, since `ARRAYFORMULA(G1:1)` would trigger an expansion by itself.

Been on this for hours without any luck, so really grateful for help.

Comment: This looks like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please add a broader description of the result that you want including sample data input and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: Sorry about that! Hope I was able to clarify

Comment: This is merely a sample sheet. Not everything in `Data!` should be imported, hence the filter.

Comment: The demo spreadsheet doesn't include a sheet with the expect result. The original Sheet1 didn't help to clarify what are you expecting as the result, by one side because the headers are the same (same name, same order) than those of the original Data sheet.

Comment: Added source data, formula input and expected result.. The data was formatted using this tool: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Formula

```
=ArrayFormula(HLOOKUP(A1:H1,Data!A:I,ROW(Data!A2:A),FALSE))
```

## Explanation

Not all the Google Sheets formulas "iterate" when they are nested inside ArrayFormula by the other hand, FILTER is similar to ArrayFormula as it returns an array of values.

Instead use nest ROW inside HLOOKUP, as it's shown on the formula section of this answer.

Comment: This works perfect, thank you so much!!!